# Code cannot be run in webstorm but can run in command-line

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I encountered this following node.js code which uses the keypress module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

// make `process.stdin` begin emitting "keypress" events 
keypress(process.stdin);

// listen for the "keypress" event 
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
  console.log('got "keypress"', key);
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

It runs fine in command-line. However, when I run it on Webstorm in debug mode, I get the error

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
              ^

TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function
```

Why is this so?

Comment: check node version in command line and in the WebStorm settings